# JSHint reports undefined global despite `globals` setting

Tags: javascript, jshint

JSHint is reporting undefined variables despite the `globals` setting. Here is a minimal example:

file.js:

```
// jshint esversion: 6, node: true
// globals Intl

'use strict';
let percent = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { style: "percent" }).format;
```

Running `jshint file.js`

```
index2.js: line 5, col 19, 'Intl' is not defined.

1 error
```

Any idea what could be wrong with my configuration? Note that there is no `.jshintrc`, the only configuration for JSHint are the comments at the beginning of `file.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I never saw the use of a simple single-line comment like `//` to configure jshint/globals.

Try with with multi-line comment style, like `/* globals MY_LIB: false */` as per defined in: http://jshint.com/docs/

Comment: Spot-on. Works with a multi-line comment. I wouldn't have expected this... considering filing a feature request to support single-line comments. Anyway, thanks!